Pysprak count based on every consective group of segment

Here is the data
For an account we have 3 segments D30,D60 and D90 I want a count for each consecutive group
these groups may have some Null values
I want to mark a flag '1' at every first occurence of each value of segment
Output should reflect 4 for each record present
as we have 2-D30 groups 1 D-60 and 1 D-90
=2+1+1=4 so the output column show have 4
I used partition by account but it's not working

Can u add the expected dataframe how it should look like at the end?
